# display moderation field in view filter

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I have webform module in drupal 7.23.I have 4 fields in name,email,message and publish fields.publish field is displayed only for admin user and not displayed for anonymous user.
publish field is a select option.This webform field is not available in filter criteria.
I want to save the content as draft and display only after admin review ie) have to add filter criteria for publish field in view.

Now I want to publish filter is not available for filter criteria.

I want to display the content if publish field value is 1

Answer (score 0):

Let me share my findings, it works for me according to your requirement.

Webforms' Select List won't work with views expose filter as it works with content type/taxonomy. See comment by webform contributor [here](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/1871406#comment-7539227)

To achieve that follow these steps:

**1st step** I created a new component in the webform named as `published?` with the type `Select options` and set its `default value` as "no" (because it won't show to other user it'll be empty so they can't set an value the you can't filter submissions) and check the **Private** check box like this

[image]

**2nd step** Create a views page for **webform submissions** like this

[image]

**3rd step** Add relations using **Webform submissions: Data** and set up like this

[image]

**4th step** Add filter criteria using **Webform submission data: Data field** field, expose it, choose `Grouped filters` radio option, select widget type as **select** and set relationship and don't save it yet

**5th step** For the group filter, there is table below (scrrenshort) you can add your values like you add value while creating the **Publish component** in webform.

[image]

I hope this'd work for you. Thank